# Ubuntu 12.10 Gnome 3 Login Screen Bad position

Tags: 12.10, gnome, ati, fglrx, gdm

#### Operating System and Config:

I have Ubuntu 12.10 with Unity removed and installed Gnome 3 desktop.

#### Everything works fine but...

When I turn on PC for the first time and Gnome loads the login screen, it is kinda *aside* not in center. I can see something but not everything.

[image: Screenshot(Print screen not working so I took photo]

If I log in, and log out again, login screen is OK, but it does not work after turning on PC for the first time, or after closing the notebook display.

#### What was I doing until the problem showed up

Recently I was trying to install original ATI drivers instead of FGLRX but it didn't work so I installed FGLRX back, this may be the problem but I am not sure.

#### Question:

How to repair it so I can login normally like before? :)

Comment: I had similar issues with gdm and fglrx and was unable to solve them. My 'solution' was to disable all screens except for my main monitor in amdcccle. Another thing you could do is to install another display manager and then use "sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager" to switch to that one. My suggestion would be lightdm, for its dependencies should be installed on your system already.

Comment: I tried lightdm , it was installed but it totally messed up my system I had to run Ubuntu in text mode, install gnome3 packages again, I dont know why it was deleted by reconfiguring but nevermind. I almost forgot that I connected my notebook to a TV recently so maybe if I do it again and disable TV through hdmi it will help. Thanks for help I will update this question if I solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution!

It is in the answer of this question [How to change the screen resolution for the gdm login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12998/how-to-change-the-screen-resolution-for-the-gdm-login-screen)