# How to change GDM resolution in Gnome-Shell 3.24 and Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: 17.04, display-resolution, gdm, gnome-shell

How can I get GDM (and the Gnome-Shell desktop) to use a specified resolution, when my LCD monitor *may* not be reporting the correct information?

- I am using Ubuntu-Gnome 17.04 with Gnome-Shell 3.24.
- GDM is displayed at `1024x768` pixels.
- My monitor's native resolution is `1280 x 1024`.
- This resolution is not listed in the Gnome-Shell Display Settings dialog.

**What I've Tried (with Partial Success)**

I am able to set this resolution using `xranr` as follows:

```
xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 
1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-1 "1280x1024_60.00"
xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode "1280x1024_60.00"
```

As suggested in an answer to [How to change the screen resolution for the GDM login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12998/how-to-change-the-screen-resolution-for-the-gdm-login-screen#14610), I created a `monitors.xml` file and moved it to `/var/lib/gdm3/.config/`.  (The `monitors.xml` file is shown below). I set the ownership and permissions as follows:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gdm gdm /var/lib/gdm3/.config/monitors.xml
```

When I restarted the computer, I found that the resolution specified in `monitors.xml` was *not* used.

Remembering that `1280 x 1024` was not listed in the Display Settings dialog, assumed that my monitor is not properly reporting its native resolution to Ubuntu.  Therefore I created a 'xorg.cong' file and placed it in `/etc/X11/`, and now the Gnome-Shell Display Settings dialog *does* show `1280 x 1024` as an option.  (The `xorg.conf` file is shown below).

Using **both** the `/var/lib/gdm3/.config/monitors.xml` file and the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file, I am able to get `1280 x 1024` resolution *after* each user logs into her/his account.

However, the GDM login screen still uses a resolution of `1024x768`.  How can I make it so that GDM also uses a resolution of `1280 x 1024`?

For reference, here is the `monitors.xml` file:

```
<monitors version="1">
  <configuration>
    <clone>no</clone>
    <output name="VGA-1">
      <vendor>unknown</vendor>
      <product>unknown</product>
      <serial>unknown</serial>
      <width>1280</width>
      <height>1024</height>
      <rate>59.894847869873047</rate>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <rotation>normal</rotation>
      <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
      <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
      <primary>yes</primary>
      <presentation>no</presentation>
      <underscanning>no</underscanning>
    </output>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```

For reference, here is the `xorg.conf` file:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Samsung SyncMaster 171N"
    Modeline    "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
    Option      "Rotate" "left"
    # Option      "PreferredMode" "1280x1024_60.00"
    # HorizSync   30.0 - 81.0 # kHz
    # VertRefresh 60.0 - 60.0 # Hz
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "AccelMethod" "sna"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "Samsung SyncMaster 171N"
    Device      "Intel"
    Defaultdepth 24
    SubSection  "Display"
        Modes   "1280x1024_60.00"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier  "Default Layout"
    Screen      "Default Screen"
EndSection
```