# Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop - Login Screen uses 100% DPI instead of 200%

Tags: nvidia, login, display-resolution

I'm using Ubuntu 23.10 x64 Desktop and the experience so far has been great, but I have an issue with the login screen: it renders at 100% DPI instead of the 200% DPI that I have setup in the system settings. I'm using a 4K monitor which makes it very difficult to read text.

Is there a way to force the login screen to render according to the DPI specified in the system settings? If it's relevant, I'm using NVIDIA proprietary drivers.

I remember having the same issue with Ubuntu 22.04 and 23.04.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. This command did the trick:

`sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml /var/lib/gdm3/.config/monitors.xml`

Source: [How to change the screen resolution for the GDM login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12998/how-to-change-the-screen-resolution-for-the-gdm-login-screen)

Comment: Thanks for this, I had a similar issue and it worked great.